# Concatenate apostrophe ( ' ) in fn:concat in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to concatenate apostrophe ( ' ) to another value in WSO2 ESB. I have tried both ' and the ASCII value but it is not working for me.

```
<property expression="get-property('uri.var.id')" name="aId"
    scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="fn:concat(get-property('aId'),''')"
    name="accId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestion

Comment: Have you tried a simple &apos; ?

Comment: post what do you want to achieve, strings before and after

Answer (score 0):

For me it was working the following way.

Declare a property with the value, you're then able to use it in your concat.

```
<property name="apos" value="'" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>

<property name="newStatement" expression="fn:concat($ctx:statement,' some value ',get-property('apos'),......." scope="operation"></property>
```

Hope that help's.